# How to get the complete string?

Tags: regex, shell

input:
  create table tbl (
    int1 int,
    vc1 varchar(5),
    vc2 varchar(^6)
    )
    dakgdkagkdsa
    asdajgdahsdha;

expected output:

```
int1 int,
vc1 varchar(5),
vc2 varchar(^6)
```

Comment: You will get much better answers if you show what code you have tried so far and what problems you were having with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a file with sed

```
sed 's/\([^(]*( \)\(.*)\)\( ).*\)/\2/;s/, /,\n/g' infile
```

If it's a var

with bash

```
var="${var#*\( }";var="${var% )*}";printf "${var//, /,$'\n'}\n"
```

With posix shell (dash)

```
var="${var#*\( }";var="${var% )*}";var2="${var#*, }";printf "%s\n" "${var%%,*}," "${var2%,*}," "${var##*, }"
```

Comment: can you please explain?